# How to get entire period aws cloud watch logs data in logs insights query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have aws cloud watch log group like "data_analysis" and retention period is 30 days and yesterday i changed the retention period to "never expires" . while query the data using "logs insights" on "data_analysis" log group still getting 30days data.  Could you please suggest the solution to get the entire data(at least 365 days)  .

Note: the query results not more than 1000  and i am adding the limit condition on "logs insights" query.

Thanks in advance